# Has the zeroth law of thermodynamics ever been proven?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

Has the [zeroth law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics) ever been proven? I know the zeroth law of thermodynamics probably follows from the second law of thermodynamics but according to [The statistical nature of the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76842/), the second law of thermodynamics probably hasn't been proven to be absolute. I see why it could be possible to show that two substances in contact will form a solubility and thermal equilibrium with each other but I don't see how to show that when ever 3 immiscible liquids are in contact with one another, they will all form a thermal and solubility equilibrium with one another.

Comment: What axioms would you use to prove them?

Comment: I can't say that this is a proof but a quick search online leads to the paper [*A mathematical proof of the zeroth “law” of thermodynamics and the
nonlinear Fourier “law” for heat flow*](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/15585/1/01_Evans_A_mathematical_proof_of_the_2012.pdf).

Comment: Thermodynamics is a phenomenological subject. The laws of TD are empirical. Rest of TD is a mathematical deduction from or logical consequence of these laws.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what temperature is. A simple statistical argument could go like this.

- the multiplicity of two systems is the product of their multiplicities
- in thermodynamic equilibrium the multiplicity is at its maximum
- $\frac{d}{dE}(\Omega_A \Omega_B) = 0$ for an infinitesimal transfer of internal energy from A to B
- the fractional change of multiplicity with internal energies ($\beta = \frac{1}{\Omega} \frac{d\Omega}{dE}$) must be equal for both systems (if $\Omega_A$ goes down by 1 ‰, $\Omega_B$ goes up by 1 ‰).
- identify $\beta = 1/kT$

If this is the case for systems A and B and for B and C, the fractional change of multiplicity with energy ($\beta$) should also be the same for A and C. At room temperature, it is about 4 % per meV, for any system.